# не получается преобразовать python в exe файл

Tags: python, pip, pyinstaller

При попытки преобразования получается ошибка

```
pyinstaller : Имя "pyinstaller" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы. 
Проверьте правильность написания имени, а также наличие и правильность пути, после чего повторите попытку.
строка:1 знак:1
+ pyinstaller <имя файла> -F
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pyinstaller:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Саму библиотеку я установил

```
pip install pyinstaller
```